# Paradox of every unit speed curve being geodesic.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $a:I\to U$ be a curve. Here, $U\subset R^{n+1}$ is open containing $S:= f^{-1}(0)$ for some smooth map $f:U\to R$ with non vanishing derivative. Assume $S$ to be oriented with unit norm $N$.

**Definition:** Geodesic curvature function $k_g$ of $a$ is defined as: $k_g(t)= (\dot a(t))'\cdot J \dot a(t)$, $Jv:= N(p)\times v, v\in T_pS, (\dot a(t))':= \dot a(t)- (\dot a(t). N(a(t)))N(a(t))$.

**Definition of geodesic:** $a$ is said to be a geodesic to $S$ if $\ddot a(t)\perp S_{a(t)}$ for all $t$.

[Here](https://dokumen.tips/documents/differential-geometry-thorpe-pdf.html?page=204) is the confusing definition. It is not clear from the definition whether it is for unit speed $a$ or for any $a$. Please clarify if you know this.

The same para in the link suggests that $a$ is geodesic iff $k_g$ is $0$ function. Let's call this **theorem**.

Consider $a(t)= (r\cos t, r\sin t, \sqrt{1-r^2})$.  Is it a geodesic on $S^2$?

Its geodesic curvature function  is $0$. But $\ddot a(t)$ is not parallel to $a(t)$ (the outward normal to $S^2$ at $a(t)$) so $a(t)$ cannot be a geodesic of $S^2$. This violates the theorem creating **paradox $1$.**

Note that dotting with $J\dot a(t)$ in the following $(\dot a(t))'= \dot a(t)- (\dot a(t)\cdot N(a(t)))N(a(t))$ gives $0$. So geodesic curvature function of every unit speed $a$ is always $0$ creating **paradox $2$.**

**Question**: What is the explanation to these paradoxes?

Comment: The geodesic curvature function for your curve $a(t)$ on the sphere is not zero.  Therefore it is not a geodesic and there is no contradiction.  The only geodesics on the round sphere are the great circles, whereas your $a(t)$ does not parametrize a great circle of the sphere unless $r=1$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Thanks for the comment. Paradox 2 shows that the geodesic curvature is 0. Can you please explain what is wrong in that calculation?

Comment: The definition of $J$ works only when $n=2$. You also have the wrong definition of $(\dot a){}'$. You forgot to differentiate again on the right-hand side. Yes, it's defined only for unit-speed curves, just as the usual definition of curvature is. Your paradoxes arise because you looked at the velocity and not at the acceleration, I presume.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thank you so much. That is **THE** problem. I applied the definition wrong. Indeed, $(\dot a(t))'= \ddot a(t)- (\ddot a(t). N(a(t)))N(a(t))$. Thanks a lot.